# How many times can an android app update be rejected before getting banned?

Tags: google-play

How many times can an Android app update be rejected before getting banned from the Play store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I read it seems like there are not set rules for the number of rejections. It is more about the reasons behind it, but it looks like it serves as a warning in itself.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2491922?hl=en